# New Tabs are opening randomly in browser

Tags: windows, google-chrome, tabs, operating-system

I use Chrome as my browser and for the past week or so, tabs have been randomly opening when I start Chrome, sometimes as I'm browsing. It started with a tab opening one day as I was watching a video, I clicked on it thinking it was a popup (like the ones that come up when you click somewhere on a website, the ones that AdBlock miss) and it was just some random forum I've never seen before. I closed it, then forgot about it. Ever since then, the same thing has been happening - random tabs will open, sometimes just 1 or 2 but sometimes there's at least 10, opening all at once.
what should i do to get rid of this problem?
[when i run chrome this popup appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMykb.png)

Comment: Settings > Reset That's the best fix!

Comment: 'I use Chrome as my browser'....  next....

Comment: Thanks for vote down

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you clicked to a link which automatically ran some malwares and installed or hooked some bad scripts into your system. I used to get same issue and I have to re-install my windows (re-install Chrome only didn't work)

Comment: yes i think we can do this
but this is not a proper solution.

Comment: if we again encountered a problem something like that, then what should we do?

Comment: It depends on what kind of 'bad program' was installed. Try to scan your installed program and check whether there's any strange one installed without your awareness. Then try to remove it completely (remove in regedit also)